# How do I trigger a pop up when certain boxes (multiple divs) become the correct color?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making an interactive puzzle where the user is supposed to change the color of particular blocks in order to make an image. In this case, I would like a pop up to appear (the pop up currently hidden) when all particular blocks are X color. I know how to trigger a 1 click pop up, but I don't know how to make it so when MULTIPLE boxes are the right color, the pop up is revealed to advance the player to the next puzzle. My sad attempt can be found at the bottom of the JS (the audio right now isn't important).

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Block Party</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="gridtest.css">
  </head>
<body>
  <div class="boxorganization">
    <div class="popup">
      <div class="congrats">puzzle <br>complete!</div>
      <div class="next">next</div>
    </div>
<!-- 20 boxes per group MAGENTA BOXES-->
      <div class="box" id="specialbox"></div><div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div>

      <div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div>

      <div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div>

      <div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div>

      <div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div>
```

```
  <audio id="coin" src="sounds/coin.mp3"></audio>
  <audio id="ding" src="sounds/ding.mp3"></audio>
  <audio id="drip" src="sounds/drip.mp3"></audio>
  <audio id="flick" src="sounds/flick.mp3"></audio>
  <audio id="power" src="sounds/power.mp3"></audio>
  <audio id="zap" src="sounds/zap.mp3"></audio>
```

```
    <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="gridtest.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

```
Here is my CSS: 



    html{
  height: 100%;
}

*, *::before, *::after{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #00008B;

}

.boxorganization{
    position: absolute;
    width: 500px;
    top: 85px;
    left: 400px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;

}
.box{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: magenta;
    /*margin: -.5px;*/
    border: 1px solid #00008B;

}

.specialbox{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: magenta;
    /*margin: -.5px;*/
    border: 1px solid #00008B;

}


.popup{
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -250px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -250px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.popupvisible{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -250px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -250px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.congrats{
  font-family: 'Primetime';
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 25%;
  top: 35%;
  color: magenta;
  opacity: 1;

}

.next{
  font-family: 'Primetime';
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 38%;
  top: 62%;
  color: magenta;
  opacity: 1;

}



/*~~~~~~~block colors~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~*/

.yellow{
  background: yellow;

}

.blue{
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(315deg, magenta 50%, yellow 50%);
  /*background: blue;*/
}

.red{
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, magenta 50%, yellow 50%);
  /*background: red;*/
}

.green{
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, magenta 50%, yellow 50%);
  /*background: green;*/
}

.white{
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(225deg, magenta 50%, yellow 50%);
  /*background: white;*/
}



/*~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~*/
```

and here is the JS:

```
    // INDEX TITLE HOVER EFFECT

$(".title").hover(function () {
  $(".title").addClass("titlehover");}, function () {
  $(".title").removeClass("titlehover");

});


// INSTRUCTIONS HOVER EFFECT

$(".instructions").hover(function () {
  $(".instructions").addClass("instructionshover");}, function () {
  $(".instructions").removeClass("instructionshover");

});

// TITLE PAGE FADE INS

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".title").hide(0).delay(100).fadeIn(2000)
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".by").hide(0).delay(700).fadeIn(2000)
});




// PAGE 1 TITLE EFFECT

$(".text").hover(function () {
  $(".text").addClass("texthover");}, function () {
  $(".text").removeClass("texthover");

});



//  BOX SOUNDS
//
// $('.box').click(function()){
//   $(this).play('coin.mp3')
// });






//  box color

$('.box').click(function(){
  $(this).addClass(function(index,currentClass){
    console.log(currentClass)

    if(currentClass == 'box'){
      $('#drip')[0].play()
      return 'yellow'
    }
    if(currentClass == 'box yellow'){
      $(this).removeClass('yellow')
      $('#ding')[0].play()
      return 'blue'
    }
    if(currentClass == 'box blue'){
      $(this).removeClass('blue')
      $('#flick')[0].play()
      return 'red'
    }
    if(currentClass == 'box red'){
      $(this).removeClass('red')
      $('#drip')[0].play()
      return 'green'
    }
    if(currentClass == 'box green'){
      $(this).removeClass('green')
      $('#ding')[0].play()
      return 'white'
    }
    if(currentClass == 'box white'){
      $(this).removeClass('white')
      $('#flick')[0].play()
    }

    // ~~~~~~~~~~~~~ I would like for popupvisible to appear when ALL of the correct blocks are turned yellow or whatever color

    if ('#specialbox' == 'box yellow'){
      $("popup").addClass('popupvisible')
      // or should it be "this" instead of popup? 
  })


});
```

Comment: You should have an event that fires when the boxes are clicked (or what ever event sets the color) that (instead of instantly showing your popup) executes a function to check the colors of all the boxes for the condition you are looking for. If the condition exists then show your popup.

Comment: You need to refer to the popup as a class in jquery, in $('.popup') instead of $('popup'). Just a tip - it'll be easier to get some answers if you post just the code related to the question.

Comment: @ScottMarcus `* {}` does not automatically affect the before and after pseudo-elements.  check this fiddle and see the difference when you remove it: https://jsfiddle.net/hhmm4dL6/

Comment: @SinanGuclu I stand corrected. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to set up a click event handler on all the boxes that record that box color and check that record upon each click to know whether or not to display the popup.

Your code is too long to modify here, but here is a scaled down example that you could implement with your code:

```js
// Get a collection of all the "cells"
var cells = document.querySelectorAll(".cell");

// Set up an array of possible colors
var colors = ["red", "green", "blue", "yellow", "orange", "gray", "aqua"];

// This is the record of which cell is what color:
var storage = {
  cell0: "",
  cell1: "",
  cell2: "",
  cell3: ""
};

// Set a click event handler on each cell
Array.prototype.slice.call(cells).forEach(function(cell, index){
  cell.addEventListener("click", function(e){

    // Change the cell color to a random color from the colors array
    var c = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
    e.target.style.backgroundColor = colors[c];
    
    // Store cell and color:
    storage["cell" + index] = c;
    
    // Debugger test
    console.clear();
    console.log(storage);
    
    // Test to make sure all cells have had an initial color set for them
    var initialized = true;
    
    for(var prop in storage){
      if(storage[prop] === ""){
        initialized = false;
        break;
      }
    }
    
    // Only check for color matches after each cell has had an initial 
    // color set for it (each cell has been clicked once).
    if(initialized){
    
      // Check to see if two adjacent cells have same color
      if(storage.cell0 === storage.cell1 ||
        storage.cell0 === storage.cell2 ||
        storage.cell1 === storage.cell3 ||
        storage.cell2 === storage.cell3){
        alert("You win!");   
      }
  
    }
  
  });
  
});
```

```css
.row1, .row2 { display:table-row; }
.cell { 
  display:table-cell; 
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
  border:1px solid black;
  padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row1">
  <div class="cell">One</div>
  <div class="cell">Two</div>
</div>

<div class="row2">
  <div class="cell">Three</div>
  <div class="cell">Four</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you click on a box, give it a class or something that indicates it was clicked/selected. You'll want to give all of the boxes a consistent class or something so that you can loop through all of them and check to see if they're selected or not. And if you loop through them all and they're all selected, show the popup. Otherwise, hide it. Here's a demo.

```js
var $boxes = $('.box');

$('.box').on('click',function() {
  var allSelected = true,
      $popup = $('.popup');
  $(this).toggleClass('selected');
  $boxes.each(function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('selected')) {
      allSelected = false;
    }
  })
  if (allSelected) {
    $popup.addClass('popupvisible');
  } else {
    $popup.removeClass('popupvisible');
  }
})
```

```css
.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: magenta;
  border: 1px solid #00008B;
  display: inline-block;
}
.selected {
  background: purple;
}
.popup {
  display: none;
}
.popupvisible {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>

<div class="popup">popup</div>
```